# How to validate jTextField if data is already exists?

Tags: java, swing, validation, jdbc, jtextfield

I have a frame that adds new data of customer info. I want to validate my `JTextField` when I enter an existing `customerName`, a message dialog box show that "Customer Name is already exists!".

Here is my code for adding new data to my database table. Where do I put those `JTextField` validation code?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
        cn.connection();
        String sql = "insert into customer(customerName, customerPhone, customerAddress, contactPerson) values('" + customerName.getText() + "','" + customerPhoneTxtField.getText() + "', '"+ textCustomerAddress.getText() +"', '"+contactPersonTxtField.getText()+"')";
        ps = cn.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer Successfully Added");

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fill in the field(s) to complete.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before inserting data into the database you should right one select statement to check if customer exists.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customerName = '"+JTextfield.getText()+"'";
```

fire this query and if it returns row then that customer name exists if customer name exists in that case you can show pop up using `JOptionPane`.

This code should go in `JButton.actionPerformed`.

Comment: thank you sir, can you make the code for that? I'm new to JAVA PROGRAMMING. :( please if it is ok for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch the exception that will be thrown if a duplicate entry in the database exists.

Alter you catch block to catch SQLException then test if this is a constraint error using [getSQLState](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState%28%29). This will happen when the state is '23'. For example

```
e.getSQLState().startsWith("23");
```

On another note its worth thinking about how to structure you code. Following the MVC pattern is a good way to decouple your user interface code from your business logic and database code. For example, try to move the Swing components into a separate class from the database code, this will allow you to develop and test each component separately, furthermore it will allow you to swap out parts of the application in future if you so wish. i.e. if you decided to use a NoSQL database rather than a SQL DB.